# Creating a stock portfolio in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-finance, yahoo-finance

I am new here and new to ruby on rails.

I am trying to create a rails app where users can create their own stock portfolios.

I want to use the yahoo finance gem but i don't know where to start .

I have created the rails login using devise .

Any tutorials out their ?

Thank you

Comment: I recommend learning to program first. One must learn to walk before running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prototype this on paper first, make a pretend portfolio on a notepad.

Once you have found what you want to store, create diagram out of it then make your models.

Comment: Thanks i will do that  sorry for the dumb question